# Double free error instead of Segmentation error

Tags: c++

Expecting Segmentation  error but getting  double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000cf4c20 ***

PFB code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
    int size;
    int *elem;
    test(int x):size(x),elem(new int[x])
    {
        cout<<"default constructor"<<endl;
    }
    test(const test & x)
    {
        cout<<"copy constructor and shallow copying";
        this->size=x.size;
        this->elem=x.elem;
    }
    ~test()
    {
        delete [] elem; 
    }
    void display()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
        cout<<*(elem+i)<<endl;

        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    test t(3);
    t.elem[0]=12;
    t.elem[1]=24;
    t.elem[2]=33;
    {
        test f(t);
        f.display();
        t.display();
    }    
    t.display();
}
```

I am trying to understand shallow copying ,and was expecting segmentation error.

Comment: In your copy constructor you are assigning elem from the source object to the destination object. When the scope of test f() ends, it calls the delete[] on its elem which points to the elem of t. Then when main goes out of scope t calls delete[] on elem, but this was already freed when f went out of scope.

Comment: It should have thrown the error before deleting the memory, when t calls display in the end

Comment: That isn't guaranteed like mentioned in the answer below. Even though you delete the memory, you don't change the elem pointer inside t to be NULL, that still points off into the same location in the heap, and even though that memory is no longer allocated, you can still access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing anything but a valid pointer to allocated memory or a `nullptr` to `delete` (or `delete[]`) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Also, since you use the pointer in the `t` object after it was passed to `delete[]` in the destruction of `f` you have *undefined behavior* already there in your last `display` call.

As to what happens when you have UB (Undefined Behavior) that's really irrelevant. Sometimes it might *seem* to work fine (like in your call to `display` after the memory have been deleted), sometimes you get a segmentation fault, sometimes you get other errors (like the double-free), sometimes you get [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Undefined behavior is, by its very definition, *undefined*.

Comment: Coming from a system that didn't *do* memory protection, it gives me the creeps when people "expect" a segfault...